# Showing $\ Z $ is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $\ X,Y $ be a r.vs , Show that for every $\ A \in \mathcal F $ , $\ Z $ is a r.v.

$$\ Z := \begin{cases} X(\omega) & \omega \in A \\ Y(\omega) & \omega \notin A \end{cases} $$

Since $\ X, Y $ is random variables, could I just set a $\ I_A $ as random variable where $\ I_A(\omega)  = 1 $ if $\ \omega \in A $ and $\ 0 $ otherwise. Then I can set $\ Z = I_A \cdot X + (1-I_A) \cdot Y $ and since $\ X, Y, I_A $ are random variables, and I know multiplication of random variable is a random variable then $\ Z $ is a random variable ?

Comment: What's your definition of r.v.?

Comment: if $\ X $ is a random variable, for every $\ t \in \mathbb R , X^{-1}[(-\infty,t]] \in \mathcal F $

Comment: Looks pretty good!